# Simple Closure example in Module Pattern not working

Tags: javascript, function, design-patterns, closures

In the simple example I want to demonstrate:

```
1. Module Pattern
2. Closure
```

I am trying to change a value of Local Variable by making use of closure. But, I cannot get it implemented (Output must be 15 in console).

**HTML**

```
<script>
function box(){
    var a;
    a=10;

    var obj = {};
    obj.func1 = function(b){
        a = a+b;
        console.log(a);
    }
    return obj;
}

box.func1(5);
</script>
```

Please, help me out in the example.

> Also, tell me have I missed any **key componenet** of **Module Pattern** in this simple example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling the `box` function. You need to put `()` after it to call it.

```js
function box(){
    var a;
    a=10;

    var obj = {};
    obj.func1 = function(b){
        a = a+b;
        console.log(a);
    }
    return obj;
}

box().func1(5);
```

But that's not really the Module pattern. For a module, you set a variable to the result of an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) that returns the object.

```js
var Box = (function(){
    var a;
    a=10;

    var obj = {};
    obj.func1 = function(b){
        a = a+b;
        console.log(a);
    }
    return obj;
})();

Box.func1(5);
```